# Bootstrap grid system side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a right container that is full in width.
And the left container to be two containers.

So left containers x would be two containers, top and bottom. Y would take up whole space on the right hand side. How should I go about doing this?

```
X   Y
X   takes up all the space
```

The below is the one which has two big containers side by side that takes up whole width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify which version of Bootstrap you are using.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap 3.x.x

Answer (score 1):

So, the easiest way I have found to do this is to go a level deeper, in your rows and columns. Here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 X1 here
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 X2 here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                 Y here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a bootply of it: http://www.bootply.com/q9SCaxVAKB

This should give you the desired setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/chickensoup64/z8ww8u89/1/) is what you are trying to achieve.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">X<br>X</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">Y</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">Takes up the full width</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You were pretty close but needed to nest the extra columns. Check out the docs for  [Nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

If you have customised the Bootstrap class names then you will need to update to your own.

Comment: @user5619184 can you link the code you are working with or provide a screen shot of your situation? I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at here.